# Pi in XTickLabels

Tags: matlab

I tried to use http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23841 to do this as follows:

```
data=rand(5);

plot(0:pi/4:pi, data,'LineWidth', 3);

format_ticks(gca,{'0', '\pi/4', '\pi/2', '3\pi/4', '\pi'},[],0:pi/4:pi)

ylim([0 1]);
xlabel('My x label')
ylabel('My y label')

fontSize = 20;

set(gca,'FontSize',fontSize)
```

However, the x axis label seems to overlap the x tick labels? Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong or can you suggest a better way to do this? Also, the font size of the axis labels does not seem to be the same as the y tick labels?

---- EDIT --------
Without using format_ticks, this seems to produce the same behavior of overlapping the xticks with the xlabel:

```
data=rand(5);

plot(0:pi/4:pi, data,'LineWidth', 3);

format_ticks(gca,{'0', '\pi/4', '\pi/2', '3\pi/4', '\pi'},[],0:pi/4:pi)

ylim([0 1]);
xlabel('My x label')
ylabel('My y label')

fontSize = 20;
set(gca,'FontSize',fontSize,'Font','symbol')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code should show ticks with pi symbols. Both axes will be labeled with Symbol fonts.

```
x=[-2*pi():.1:2*pi()];
plot(x,pi*sin(x))

set(gca,...
 'xlim',[-2*pi() 2*pi()],...
 'xtick',[-2*pi():pi()/2:2*pi()],...
 'xticklabel',{'-2p' '-3p/2' '-p' '-p/2' '0' 'p/2' 'p' '3p/2' '2p'},...
 'ylim',[-pi() pi()],...
 'ytick',[-pi():pi()/2:pi()],...
 'yticklabel',{'-p' '-p/2' '0' 'p/2' 'p'},...
 'fontname','symbol',...
 'fontsize',20)

xlabel('angle \phi from -2\pi to 2\pi',...
 'fontname','helvetica',...
 'fontsize',30)
ylabel('\pi*sin(\phi)',...
 'fontname','helvetica')
```

[image: same fonts for bot axes]

For different fonts for different axes:

```
x=[-2*pi():.1:2*pi()];
ax1=axes;
ax2=axes;
plot(x,sin(x),'parent',ax1)

set(ax1,...
 'xlim',[-2*pi() 2*pi()],...
 'xtick',[],...
 'xticklabel',{},...
 'ylim',[-1 1],...
 'ytick',[-1:.5:1],...
 'yticklabel',{'-a' '-a/2' '0' 'a/2' 'a'},...
 'fontsize',20)

ylabel(ax1,'a\cdotsin(\phi)',...
 'fontname','helvetica',...
 'fontsize',30)

set(ax2,...
 'xlim',[-2*pi() 2*pi()],...
 'xtick',[-2*pi():pi()/2:2*pi()],...
 'xticklabel',{'-2p' '-3p/2' '-p' '-p/2' '0' 'p/2' 'p' '3p/2' '2p'},...
 'ylim',[-1 1],...
 'ytick',[],...
 'yticklabel',{},...
 'fontname','symbol',...
 'fontsize',20,...
 'position',get(ax1,'position'),...
 'color','none')

xlabel(ax2,'angle \phi from -2\pi to 2\pi',...
 'fontname','helvetica')
```

[image: Dfferent fonts for each axis]

Comment: Ah I see, I thought set(gca,'FontName','helvetica') would reset it, but I have to include that in the xlabel calls. Thank you!

Comment: First image was exported by `export_fig` to pdf and then to png. The second one was exported directly to png with standard MATLAB tool.

I don't know why the y axes severed :(

Comment: I think it should be pointed out more clearly that the "trick" is, not to use Tex to get pi-symbols but a font. Still, a nice way to do this.

Comment: Well, ad weird thing about it - it works fine on matlab, but with `print -despc figure`, the resulting `epsc` figure has `$\neq$` symbol instead of pi. Can you think why's that?

Comment: Well, as it in the beginning of the answer, ticks are displayed using a *symbol* font so possible problem is with using the symbol font within print method. Note that there are several safe fonts for export_fig (I have found 8 of them) too.

Answer (score 1):

with MATLAB-help I would solve it like this:

```
figure(1)
data=rand(5);
plot(0:pi/4:pi, data,'LineWidth', 3);
fontSize = 20;
set(gca,'FontSize',fontSize)
set(gca,'XTick',0:pi/4:pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',{'0', 'pi/4', 'pi/2',
'3pi/4', '\pi'})
ylim([0 1]);
xlabel('My x label') 
ylabel('My y label')
```

Here the second but not nice possibilty. You don't use XTickLabel. You create text instead:

```
figure(1)
data=rand(5);
plot(0:pi/4:pi, data,'LineWidth', 3);
fontSize = 20;
set(gca,'FontSize',fontSize)
set(gca,'XTick',0:pi/4:pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[])
text(0,0,'\pi','VerticalAlignment','Top')
text(pi/4,0,'\pi/2','VerticalAlignment','Top')
text(pi/2,0,'\pi/2','VerticalAlignment','Top')
text(3*pi/4,0,'3\pi/4','VerticalAlignment','Top')
text(pi,0,'\pi','VerticalAlignment','Top')
ylim([0 1]);
xlabel('My x label')
ylabel('My y label')
```

You can do the text() with a for as well.

More automatic:

```
figure(1)
data=rand(5);
plot(0:pi/4:pi, data,'LineWidth', 3);
fontSize = 15;
set(gca,'FontSize',fontSize)
sep = 0:0.25:1; % only here you setup
set(gca,'XTick',sep*pi)
set(gca,'XTickLabel',[])
for n = 1:length(sep)
   text(sep(n)*pi,0,[num2str(sep(n)),'\pi'],...
      'VerticalAlignment','Top',...
      'HorizontalAlignment','Center')
end
ylim([0 1]);
xlabel('My x label')
ylabel('My y label')
```

Comment: From MATLAB:

FontSize... MATLAB does not display x-, y-, and z-axis text labels in a new font size until you manually reset them (by setting the XLabel, YLabel, or ZLabel properties or by using the xlabel, ylabel, or zlabel command). Tick mark labels change immediately.

I have edit this in the answer

Comment: Those "pi"s in your XTickLabel will not show up as the "pi" symbol though right (but rather just the letters "p" and "i")?

Comment: As far as I know it is not possible to use the latex interpreter within the XTICKLABEL. So you can't show pi as greek in this case.
If you really need the greeg and you don't want to photoshop it there a a other hacky possibility I will add under my answer above...

Comment: @Alex44: Why you don't set all `gca` paramaters at once?

Comment: I don't really like it. For me it is an easier overview and handling. But you can do it as well all in one.

Comment: @Alex44 This 'text' method is a bit too manual for my taste :(

Comment: I can give you an automatized version as last try. If you find a easier way... let me know.

Answer (score 1):

David having fought Matlab's data visualization tool many many times, I would suggest just saving your figure as an image and creating the data labels in photoshop, microsoft word, or the editor of you choice.  It will be less time, less headache, and will end up looking nicer (anti-aliased text etc).

Comment: I woud disagree. Setting all in MATLAB and exporting into `pdf` or `eps` gives very nice and acurate images. See `export_fig` package.

Comment: @Crowley But is there a better way to use \pi inside Matlab?

Comment: If you don't mind different fonts or you are satisfied with Computer Modern you can use TeX interpreter. Otherwise you have to use `Symbol` font or "photoshop" your images.

Comment: @Crowley I edited the question with code using 'symbol' font, but the same problem happens - the xticks overlap the xlabel, and font size does not change.

Comment: @Crowley Yes, it is possible to get nice figures in Matlab.  But it is allot of time an effort to do things that are trivial with other readily available packages. Why bother?

Comment: Peter has a point when it comes to more extravagant tick-labels, where the use of a font might not suffice. I struggled with subscripts for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

To the discussion to the post of Peterm:

It's possible to plot the graphik in the normal way. after that you edit the plot with the plot tools GUI offered in the figure window. There you can drag the objects to other position, edit the lines etc.
After you finished you can generate code from this by selecting Menu->File->Generate Code. Now you will find a code snipped in the MATLAB-Editor, whish you can copy paste to your application/code to reuse it.
So it will be more easy to edit the whole plot instead to code it by yourself.

Comment: Ah, I always forget about this. I'll try it out next time.